# Selected edges cannot be linked

Tags: edges

I was follow a tutorial to try form a face by pressing f and link edges, but the result was different from the tutorial.

Tutorial pic:
[image]

My attempt (two edges is selected)[image]

Result:[image]

I don't want redo the whole thing, please let me know what is the problem. Thank You

[image]

Comment: Try this: select the two edges, CTRL E and then choose 'Bridged edge loops'

Comment: You cannot connect vertices between meshes of two different objects. They have to be part of the same object. Your eye parts are the object "Circle", the nose contour is "Circle.001". Join the meshes with Ctrl+J, that's either what they did in the tutorial as well or they didn't create two separate objects in the first place. I can only recommend you pay close attention to what is shown in tutorials you are watching.

Comment: @PepAndorra That will not work on separate objects.

Comment: I do believe you should redo the tutorial. That's how tutorials work. There is a lot of redoing involved, but then you learn.

Comment: Please add a link to the tutorial! As it stands you have two seperate objects selected, the outline of the face and the eyes.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to make a face between edges of two separate objects. It only works on a single object. You should go to object mode, select the two mesh objects and merge them with Ctrl + J, then if you come back to Edit mode, it will work as expected.

Comment: thank you so much !!! It work !!!